# Show fraction as it is in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, equations

I have an excel formula: `=(3+2)/2`
which outputs: `2.5`
I want the cell to appear exactly like: `(3+2)/2`
and also use it in calculations. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If you want to use the result of a formula in a calculation, you must calculate it first. If you want to see the formula, then in another cell you can use: `=FORMULATEXT(A1)` (assuming your formula is in cell `A1`)

Answer (score 1):

Under the formula Tab,

Look for an option called 'Show Formulas' use this to turn on/off.

You can also use a formula to view another cells exact forumula, depending on which version of excel you use:

```
=FORMULATEXT(A1)
```

Will deiplay the formula form cell A1